# What are non-reciprocal bandpass filters?

Tags: filter, electromagnetism

I am not an electrical engineer. I have come to know about a term called as "Non-reciprocal Bandpass filters" which seems to be useful to me.

Here are some links to the papers (unfortunately there is no proper citation to find definition of the term)

[link1](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6353237)
[link2](http://www.jpier.org/PIERM/pier.php?paper=15110903)
[link3](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8910875)

I would like to know if they are nothing but a type of isolator. Are these devices discussed in any book?

Comment: Where's the hyperlink to the term and where you found it and what other sources you looked at that contain it. Why does it appear useful to you? Asking for books is a shopping question and off-topic.

Comment: Well I just found such a term online, and I am myself searching for its' definition. I am a researcher in Quantum Optics and I find that it is relevant to my work. i am not shopping for books.

Comment: Never heard that term, but functionally it seems to be an isolator used at RF frequencies.

Comment: @user1850479 I also have a hunch, hence I asked. Thanks for considering my question.

Comment: @BrianDrummond It seems you deleted your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this patent application](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/y2015/0255846.html):

> A nonreciprocal bandpass filter is one that only allows
> electromagnetic waves (signals) to flow in one direction.

It seems to be a way to eliminate circulators or other expensive devices in order to reduce the effect of reflections on a driving circuit.

Comment: Yes, I feel they are called bandpass filters as they allow non-reciprocity in only a small band of frequencies. Thanks for the help.It seems to be a relatively new term cropped up by researchers.